# Modelica style guide

Tags: coding-style, modelica

For many programming languages there are style guides available,
e.g. [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for Python, this [Matlab style guide](http://www.datatool.com/downloads/matlab_style_guidelines.pdf) or the [style guides by Google](https://google.github.io/styleguide/).
For Modelica I found the [conventions described in the Users Guide](https://build.openmodelica.org/Documentation/Modelica.UsersGuide.Conventions.html),
but is there something more comprehensive available?
And, ideally, a tool that helps with the re-formatting, indentation etc.?

Comment: One link is now only in web archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20070126105829/http://www.datatool.com/downloads/matlab_style_guidelines.pdf

Comment: There is a proposal to update the Users Guide you link to https://github.com/modelica/ModelicaStandardLibrary/pull/4221

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The guidelines in the Modelica User's Guide are the only ones I am aware of.  The topic has been discussed several times at the design meetings and [I've written one paper](https://www.modelica.org/events/Conference2003/papers/h31_parser_Tiller.pdf) that discussed the topic but didn't really propose concrete guidelines.

Part of the issue is that while the Modelica Association might have their guidelines (as your've seen), they don't represent any particular business or industries guidelines which might be different.  In other words, I could envision having many different guidelines floating around that are tailored to specific types of models or specific industry conventions.  But the Modelica ones are the only ones I am specifically aware of (although it would not surprise me if large organizations using did have their own formal style guidelines).

Comment: yeah, this is heavily community dependent everywhere. For example, for C++, there are probably about 5 different major style choices, and innumerable smaller ones, whereas for Python, PEP8 was proposed early on, and mostly everybody just goes with that, which I find very convenient.

Comment: Any recommendations in the area of thermo-fluid modeling?

Comment: https://simulationresearch.lbl.gov/modelica/userGuide/development.html#style-guide

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile there are two command line tools which format Modelica code quite well:

- [mofmt](https://github.com/ErykMroczek/mofmt): a python package installable with pip or pipx.
- [modelica-fmt](https://github.com/urbanopt/modelica-fmt): a tool written in go. Binaries are available in the tags section. Apparently development has stopped in 2021 with v0.2.